# React multiple onChange event... one for Validation one for Formatting input

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I need a solution to format a Phone number field to format (123) 456-7890

Currently using common handleChange function to handle all input onChange event and JOI for validation.
Someone please assist on this?

```
import React from "react";

const Input = ({ name, label, error, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <div className="form-group">
      <label htmlFor={name}>{label}</label>
      <input
        {...rest}
        name={name}
        id={name}
        className="form-control form-control-sm"
      />
      {error && <div className="fv-help-block">{error}</div>}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Input;
```

Reusable component

```
renderInput(name, label, type = "text") {
    const { data, errors } = this.state;

    return (
      <Input
        type={type}
        name={name}
        value={data[name]}
        label={label}
        onChange={this.handleChange}
        error={errors[name]}
      />
    );
  }
```

Input field with name & lable

```
{this.renderInlineInput("client.phoneNo","Phone #")}
```

Reusable onChange Event:

```
handleChange = ({ currentTarget: input }) => {
    const errors = { ...this.state.errors };
    const errorMessage = this.validateProperty(input);
    if (errorMessage) errors[input.name] = errorMessage;
    else delete errors[input.name];

    const data = { ...this.state.data };
    data[input.name] = input.value;

    this.setState({ data, errors });
  };
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_pattern.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to create a mask for your number to give it the format that you want.

I've not used this library before, but you could try using https://imask.js.org/

The example they give for a phone mask is

```
var phoneMask = IMask(
  document.getElementById('phone-mask'), {
    mask: '+{7}(000)000-00-00'
  });
```

It looks fairly easy to use, but you would need to handle your phone input differently in your general `handleChange` function.

Or you might want to make another component for `PhoneInput`ing that handles the mask specifically...

Comment: Thanks @NathTech. Your suggestion to create another component works well!!!

Comment: No problem. Glad it was helpful